# Is this usage correct i.e. "Reflect off of"?

Tags: prepositions

I came across the following sentence somewhere.

> You will encounter its(=a building) dome, accompanied with a glare of
>   sunlight ***reflecting off of*** it from all around the campus and even
>   outside the University borders!

I can't dig the use "reflect" with two prepositions off and of. Can anyone explain what does that mean, and when do we write such sentences?

Answer (score 9):

It's a matter of style and good usage. It's generally agreed that *of* is not necessary after *off* in such sentences.

Chicago Manual of Style recommends this:

> **off.** Never put **of** after this word {we got off the bus}.

Cambridge Grammar of the English Language says this:

> **Off** licenses  an  **of** phrase only in  AmE  (%He  fell  off of the  wall).

There's a limited amount of prepositions that select *of* as head of their complement: *because,  exclusive,  irrespective, abreast,  ahead,  instead,  regardless,  upward(s), 
east,  north,  south,  west,  alongside,  inside, out,  outside*. With *off* it's optional.

> She took it **out of** the box
>
> She pulled it **off** the shelf.

Comment: While not necessary, it's not technically *wrong*, and the construction is commonly used by (AmEng) native speakers. (Also you have "ii" and "iii" in your prepositions list -- are those numerals? Because "in of", which I first thought was the original typo, is not a usage I've heard of.)

Comment: Sorry, these are typos :)

Answer (score 4):

*Off of X* = *away from X* and started/restarted from X - i.e. something began from or touched X then went away from it.

> I went off of 5th street = I went to or was at 5th street then I went away from it
>
> The ball bounced off of the wall = The ball touched the wall then moved away from it.

*Reflect*, *ricochet*, and similar words can all use *off of*.